# Connecting Bluemix virtual sensors to an instance of Spark service

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud, spark-streaming

I am new to bluemix and also Apache Spark. I just wanted to do a small task using IBM analytics for Apache Spark where I want to create a virtual sensor using Bluemix's virtual sensors (https://virtualsensors.mybluemix.net/) and use that generated data as input to the spark streaming service and do some analytics based on the input data. But, I don't know exactly how to connect the instances of those two application and I am stuck. It would be great if someone could help me.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation the Virtual Sensors just emit their sensor data using MQTT, so I imagine this would be as easy as importing an MQTT library in your language of choice and simply connecting that to the Virtual Sensors.

You haven't really specified what language you're working with on the Spark side, but they'll probably all shake out to either:

1. [Paho](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/) (Python, Java, Scala)
2. [Scala-MQTT-client](https://github.com/fcabestre/Scala-MQTT-client) (specifically Scala)

For how to use it, the Paho project also includes some basic documentation about how MQTT works.

Some of the other basics are covered in the [MQTT FAQ](http://mqtt.org/faq) and [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=exMm-fmU5ck).

If you need to add the JAR to your notebook, you should be able to use the %AddJar command.  You can read about that [here](https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/start-developing-with-spark-and-notebooks/) -- scroll down to the section titled "Deploy your custom library jar to a Jupyter Notebook" for the instructions and example use.

Answer (score 0):

I would like you to go through [this recipe](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/spark-streaming-ibm-watson-iot-platform-integration/) that shows how to configure the Apache Spark Streaming running in IBM Bluemix to get data from the actual sensor devices. I believe, you can just tweak the topic id to get the data from virtual sensor as well.

Also, look at the [Github project](https://github.com/sathipal/spark-streaming-mqtt-with-security_2.10-1.3.0?cm_mc_uid=62102911539814515544301&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1457423461) that shows how to create the Spark-mqtt-connector Dstream such that the Spark service can consume the events in real-time.